# How to cut a number in excel based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want  to  cut two numbers in two cells  from right side and to find at what point the number become equal  and print that number in another cell  as described in the picture

[image]

any one please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually comparing two numbers, they are strings (because you have a leading zero).  You can easily do this without VBA using the Left function.

[image]

And here's the same thing showing the formulae:

[image]

Or you can do it in VBA:

```
Public Function CompareTwoNumbers(num1 As String, num2 As String) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim temp1 As String, temp2 As String

For i = Len(num1) To 1 Step -1

    temp1 = Left(num1, i)
    temp2 = Left(num2, i)

    If temp1 = temp2 Then
        CompareTwoNumbers = temp1
        Exit Function
    End If

Next

CompareTwoNumbers = "The numbers do not match"

End Function
```

Comment: hi steve example was perfect but i need one more thing that was when first time condition became true in your example 0785 ,the value 0785 must be printed in another cell , is it possible?.

Comment: You could use the Len function to work out how long the result is (i.e. 0785 = 4).  Then you would have both 0785 and 4 as your answers.  Is this what you mean?